# is it possible to do stripe card payment totally from the backend using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Is it possible to directly pass card details in the backend and pay using stripe?

Can anyone help me with this?

Any reference doc to build stripe payment from the backend will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure it is, but handling card details on the back end means *your* servers sharing responsibility for handling users' card numbers. It means you are that much more exposed to be hacked. It means that you will therefore need extra vigilance and insurance if you want to be ethical, and might need to be able to prove it both to keep your financial institution happy AND in case of any legal matters.

Not a technical answer, I know, but be sure you realize that part of this isn't a technical question.

Comment: I will be encrypting the data from the front end and sending it to the backend. 

Could you guide me with some reference doc that I can use to build stripe payment with just the backend?